# if $\nabla f \neq 0$ then $\{x: f(x) = 0\}$ has zero volume

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, derivatives

$U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, and $f: U \to \mathbb R$ is a $C^1 $ function such that $\nabla f \neq 0$ everywhere.

Define $A = \{x \in U: f(x) = 0\}$.

Show that $A$ and $\partial A$ have zero volume.

**Here is what I did:**

Suppose $A$ actually has volume. Then the interior $A^\circ$ is not empty. This means it contains some small closed ball $B \subset A^\circ \subseteq A$.

We have that $f(x) = 0$ on $B$, so $f$ is constant there, so the gradient is zero there, which is a contradiction, hence it can't be that $A$ has volume.

Is this correct? How would I prove that $\partial A$ has zero volume?

Comment: By volume, you mean its Jordan content. Right? For the second one, you need to use Stokes' theorem I guess.

Comment: By $X$ has zero volume I mean that $X$ can be covered by countably many boxes $B_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}v(B_i) < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$.

Comment: We never used or learnt Stoke's theorem in class so I highly doubt that's the case.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But I highly doubt that you've never seen the Stokes' theorem in your life. It's a standard theorem that is taught in multivariable calculus. Measure theory is one step above calculus. Sometimes it's called by other names such as Green's theorem, the fundamental theorem of calculus, etc.

Comment: In case you have never heard the name of Stokes' theorem, do you know something like this? $${\displaystyle \int _{\mathrm {Vol} }\nabla f\,d_{\mathrm {Vol} }=\oint _{\partial \mathrm {Vol} }f\,d{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}\,.}$$

Comment: I know of stokes theorem. I'm just saying we aren't allowed to use it since it wasn't taught in this class.

Comment: I don't think it's unacceptable to use a theorem from an earlier course in a more advanced course. Anyway, I suspect that your argument for the first case is wrong too. Consider irrational numbers intersected with the interval $[0,1]$, i.e. $A=\mathbb{Q}^c \cap [0,1]$. Then $A^{\circ}=\emptyset$ but $l(A)=1$. Hence, saying that because something has volume, its interior must be nonempty is not right even in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're right, my argument fails. Well, I'm open to new ideas. I'll try to think of something new too

Comment: Do you know the local normal form for submersions?

Comment: Not a clue what that is.

Comment: Personally I do not know why is there the condition $\vec\nabla f(x)\neq0$. I will prove it as follows: $$V=\iiint_Df(x)\,\mathrm dD=\iiint_D0\,\mathrm dD=0.$$

Comment: I think it was given to us so we can use the implicit function theorem.

Answer (score 2):

A possible idea:

take $a\in A$. Then $f(a)= 0$. Since $\nabla f(a) \neq 0$ we have that for some $i$ between $1$ and $n$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a) \neq 0$. Without loss of generality, assume $i = n$

From the implicit function theorem, there is an open set $W$ containing $(a_1,a_2, \dots a_{n-1})$, and there is an open set $V$ containing $a_n$, and there is a $C^1$ function $g:W \to V$ such that $g(a_1,a_2, \dots, a_{n-1})=a_n$, and for all $w \in W$ we have $f(w,g(w)) = 0$.

Consider the graph of the function $g$: $\Gamma_g = \{(w,g(w)), w\in W\}$. This is a zero volume set, since it's a graph of a $C^1$ function, but also $\Gamma_g \subseteq A$.

Maybe we can cover $A$ by countably many $\Gamma_g$?

Comment: Yup, that's more or less the idea. To conclude, note we have shown the open set $\tilde V = W \times V$ contains $a$ and satisfies $A \cap \tilde V = \Gamma_g.$ Now we can apply this to a countable (relatively) dense subset of $A,$ using the fact that $\mathbb R^n$ is separable.